# mysql trigger for phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

i want to create a trigger in which
first the value is calculate from entry_table
i have created a query to calculate the value which is

> ```
> SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT account), SUM(amount) FROM entry GROUP BY account
> ```

and then inserted the count values to another table called total_table

entry table

[image]

totals table [image]

my trigger query

> ```
>  INSERT INTO totals (SUM_A, SUM_B, SUM_C )
>
>  SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT account), SUM(amount) FROM entry GROUP BY account
> ```

Comment: Why do want to calculate all the values again and again? and insert them as duplicates in `totals`?

Comment: i want to update by mistake i write inserted

Answer (score 0):

This trigger helpful to you.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `enter_value`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `enter_value` AFTER INSERT ON `entry_table`
 FOR EACH ROW begin

    IF NEW.account = 'sum_a' then
      INSERT INTO totals table (SUM_A) 
      SELECT sum(amount) FROM entry where account = 'sum_a' GROUP BY account;
    ELSE IF NEW.account = 'sum_b' then
      INSERT INTO totals table (SUM_B) 
      SELECT sum(amount) FROM entry where account = 'sum_b' GROUP BY account;
    ELSE IF NEW.account = 'sum_c' then
      INSERT INTO totals table (SUM_C) 
      SELECT sum(amount) FROM entry where account = 'sum_c' GROUP BY account;
    END IF;

END
```

> If you fetch any problem let me know

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'sum_a' then
      INSERT INTO totals table (SUM_A) 
      SELECT sum(amoun' at line 4

Comment: @Raahull use single `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @Raahull Try now, he forgot to put `END IF` at the end.

Comment: @Shaharyar where to put  END IF